# User generated photos Android

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph, facebook-apps

Facebook's documentation says:

```
image[{array-index}][url]
image[{array-index}][user_generated]
```

how do I put that in a `Bundle` ?

I'm currently doing

```
params.putString("image","<url>");
```

I also tried

```
Bundle temp = new Bundle().
temp.putString("url","<url>");
temp.putString("user_generated",true);

params.putBundle("image",temp);
```

but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

The answer is as simple as:

```
p.putString("image[0][url]", "<url>");
p.putBoolean("image[0][user_generated]", true);
```